# Opening Phone app using button title

Tags: ios, uibutton, openurl

I have a UIButton with a telephone number as a title.

Will this code open the phone app with the title number?

```
- (IBAction)callContact:(id)sender 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: 
        [NSURL URLWithString:telfButton.titleLabel.text]];
}
```

It is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what the URL is.
If its just `3033749943` it won't work. But `tel://3033749943` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answer you have to use "tel://" to launch the phone app and dial the number. However, you can use `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat` to add the number in the buttons title after "tel://".

```
- (IBAction)callContact:(id)sender 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",telfButton.titleLabel.text]];
}
```